# colorAccent not working before befor api 21

Tags: android, android-styles

I am using custom theme for date picker 
   This is the custom style I am using for date picker

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/applicationColor</item>


    </style>
```

While it works correctly on devices post API 21,the colorAccent part does not work below API 21,As it does not select its default color. If I set properties like background color in style then it does not work as expected as only some part of date picker dialog appers in that color. Is it possible to set theme similarly in API below 21 ?

Comment: Date, time and number pickers are not material design below API 21 so they're not respecting `colorAccent`. Try this https://github.com/consp1racy/android-commons/blob/6288208af76a27af414cce0f0de45879ee6f8661/commons/src/main/java/net/xpece/android/widget/XpDatePicker.java You'll have to copy `XpDatePicker`, `XpTimePicker` and `XpNumberPicker` to your project. Then use their public methods to at least change divider color.

Comment: I don't want to change all of that..I just need the overall theme to be of a particular colour.

Comment: It's not as simple as changing one theme attribute below API 21. You will have to change the color on every view yourself. Or get a backport library.

Comment: Ok ..thank you (Y)